# A Question about Functions

Tags: vb.net

I know this may sound like a dumb question but I got to know since I have been trying to find an answer but can't find any. I noticed that in some functions, after the parentheses, the function is assigned a type? For example

`Public Function getConn(ByVal AppId As String, ByVal TranId As String)` **As String**

and it returns a value call sRet

After the parentheses, why is there an "As String"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's defining the return type.

If you did something like

```
connection = getConn("1", "2")
```

then connection would be a string, that probably contains the connection string.

You can do other return types as well, such as Int, Float etc.

Comment: Ah ok thanks, it makes more sense. Just one more question, Since both parameters are already set As String, isn't the return type already implied and don't need the additional As String after the close parentheses?

Comment: Not at all.  You could do a `GetZipcode(String username) as int` which would let you pass in a string, but return an int.  The parameters passed in are no indication of the return types.